# How to know what warehouse snowpipe uses to process data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Like the title says, I'd like to know how can I know in which warehouse does snowpipe runs the copy queries to load data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake uses an "internal" warehouse (a Snowflake-provided warehouses), called Snowpipe to process pipes, documented in this link which reviews this pretty well.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-billing.html#viewing-the-data-load-history-for-your-account

I hope this helps...Rich